# Excel xlsx file to sql server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, xlsx

I'm trying to export xlsx file to sql server table.

```
select * 
FROM OPENROWSET
('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', 'Excel 12.0;Database=D:\WORK\AHP\k_i_c.xlsx;HDR=YES', 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

I have error:

```
Cannot create an instance of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".
```

Before that I did:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'ad hoc distributed queries', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO

EXECUTE MASTER.dbo.xp_enum_oledb_providers
```

Then I checked "Allow inprocess" in SQLOLEDB in Server Objects/Linked Servers/Providers.

I have Windows 10, SQL Server 2014 Management Studio, Office 2010 v.14 32bit.

Comment: And SQL Server is x64 and Office is x86?

Comment: Yes. I managed to import via SQL Server Wizard.

Comment: Have you tried `EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' , N'AllowInProcess' , 1
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' , N'DynamicParameters' , 1
GO`?